# Why does it output -294967296

Tags: java, arrays, integer

So in leetcode 4 sum there is a test case [1000000000,1000000000,1000000000,1000000000] and for some reason the addition of these is equal to -294967296 and i do not understand how exactly this works i assumed it was because the actual answer is larger than max val of an int but i tried that and it just threw an error instead so why does that not happen here

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> fourSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        if(target>Integer.MAX_VALUE||target<Integer.MIN_VALUE){
            return new ArrayList();
        }
        int lb =0;
        int ub  = nums.length-1;
        int sum = 0;
        HashSet<List<Integer>> ans = new HashSet();
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        for(int i = 0;i<nums.length;i++){

            for(int j = i+1;j<nums.length;j++){
                lb = j+1;
                ub = nums.length-1;
                while(lb<ub){

                    sum = nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[lb]+nums[ub];
                    if(sum==-294967296){
                        System.out.println(sum);
                        System.out.println(nums[i]);
                        System.out.println(nums[j]);
                        System.out.println(nums[lb]);
                        System.out.println(nums[ub]);
                    }
                    if(sum==target){
                        ans.add(Arrays.asList(nums[i],nums[j],nums[lb],nums[ub]));
                        lb++;
                        ub--;
                    }else if(sum<target){
                        lb++;
                    }else{
                        ub--;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        List<List<Integer>> ret = new ArrayList(ans);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

this is the code i wrote and i dont think there is an issue here

Comment: Check for integer overflow.

Comment: What error are you getting? What is this code's function? What inputs are you giving it? When I run `fourSum(new int[]{ 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000, 1000000000 }, -294967296)` it doesn't give me any error.

Comment: For reference, this seems to be the LeetCode page for the problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/4sum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all...

```
if(target>Integer.MAX_VALUE||target<Integer.MIN_VALUE){
    return new ArrayList();
}
```

This `if` statement will never trigger because an `int` *by definition* cannot be smaller than `Integer.MIN_VALUE` or larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. In other words, `target > Integer.MAX_VALUE || target < Integer.MIN_VALUE` will always evaluate to `false`.

The maximum value an `int` variable can hold is 2^31 - 1, or 2,147,483,647. Your sum is exactly 4 billion which causes your integer variable to overflow.

You really should use `long` variables to operate on values of this magnitude.

**P.S.** What does `integer overflow` mean? `byte`, `short`, `int` and `long` numbers in Java are stored using the [2's complement system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The first bit of the value stores the sign. If it's equal to 0, the number is positive; if it's 1, the number is negative. Thus the largest positive value an `int` can hold is 01111111111111111111111111111111 in binary. This number happens to be 2,147,483,647 in decimal. If you add 1 to it, it becomes 10000000000000000000000000000000, which is -2,147,483,648 in decimal (it's negative because the first bit is now 1).

Answer (score 0):

This is a calculation overflow. Simply put 4 * 1000000000 exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE. Though the processor won't limit your result but wraps it into its available bits.

You can try using hexadecimal representation: 4 * 0x3B9ACA00 = 0xEE6B2800

```
System.out.println(0xEE6B2800);
```

Just another tip: Your code has a high complexity already. You should declare variables where you need them. The declarations of lb and ub could go into the for-j-loop, sum is only used within the while-loop. The initial values are never used before set to other values.

In my career I found lots of such top-level variables which ware reused in following code for other purposes and no one could really predict which values they have.